# Check if today is in an array of dates

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to run a script that checks today's date against a predetermined array of dates (Public Holidays). However, I'm struggling to understand the array setup. I have got the script working without the array using just a single date however don't get how to turn it to an array with multiple options to check.

The code written is below;

```
var today = new Date().getHours();
var daycheck = new Date().getDay();
var holidayArray = new Date('12/19/2019');
var todayDate = new Date();

if (holidayArray.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0) == todayDate.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0)) {
  alert('This is outside of business hours (Public Holiday).');
  window.history.back();
} else {
  if (today <= 8 || today >= 17) {
    alert('This is outside of business hours. General access is provided from 9am - 5pm Monday to Friday');
    window.history.back();
  }
  else {
    if (daycheck == 0 || daycheck == 6) {
      alert('This is outside of business hours(weekend).');
      window.history.back();
    }
    else {
      if (confirm('It is currently within business hours during the week. You can now continue.')) {
        window.location.href = "https://URL";
      }
      else { window.history.back() }
    }
  }
}
```

I need assistance in adding additional dates to the `holidayArray` variable, as every time I try something it does not work.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you allowed to use libraries? Something like [Luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/) would make this far easier, especially if you have to take time zones into account

Comment: SO you need to loop over the array

Answer (score 2):

In JavaScript you create arrays via this syntax: `var holidayArray = [new Date("12/19/2019"), new Date("12/20/2019"), new Date("12/21/2019")]`

And then you have to loop through this array, for example:

```
for (let holiday of holidayArray) {
    // Place your IF statements in here and make your checks against the value "holiday". For example:

    if (holiday.setHours(0,0,0,0) == todayDate.setHours(0,0,0,0)) {
        alert("This is outside of business hours (Public Holiday).");
        window.history.back();
    }

}
```

This will sequentially loop through your array. `holiday` will represent each value in the array as it goes through it.

Answer (score 1):

Array.some() is what you need:

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_some.asp

Put your above code into a checkDate function, and then copy the example below

```
function checkDate(d){
    return d.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0) == todayDate.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0))
}
let isHoliday = holidayArray.some(checkDate);
```

Also you need to make holidayArray be an array of Dates instead of a Date